# Microsoft Syntex not triggering after power automate saved documents into a library

Tags: sharepoint, artificial-intelligence, power-automate

I am using Microsoft Syntex Content understanding on a specific Document library in Sharepoint (M365).When files are dragged into the library manually, content processing starts as expected and delivers results.

When files are added to the library with a power automate flow, the content processing does not start (not until some other files are added manually again).

Any ideas if this is a config issue?

I tried waiting (files had not been processed on the next day), checked licensing and permissions. The issue stayed, content understanding starts only when triggered by manual file upload.

Answer (score 0):

We opened a case with MS Support and it started working a few days later. Case closed by Engineer without further explanation.

From our side we made sure we had the correct licensing in place, eliminated all complexity from power automate so that only plain pdfs landed in the syntex library.